# Display legend only for values present at the bar-chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, bar-chart

I would like to display the legend only for values present in the charts. In other word, if value is zero or null in chart the legend of this items not display.

Which settings should I use for bar-chart?

Comment: Simple or from highcharts (pro edition)?

Comment: Simple and not pro edition.